# thead fixed and scrollable page (not tbody)

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-wrap">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th title="Timezone">TZ</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th title="Time To Waypoint">TTW</th>
                    <th title="Distance To Waypoint">DTW</th>
                    <th title="Distance To Go">DTG</th>
                    <th title="True Wind Direction">TWD</th>
                    <th title="True Wind Speed">TWS</th>
                    <th title="True Wind Angle">TWA</th>
                    <th title="Bearing To Waypoint - Heading">BTW</th>
                    <th>Sail</th>
                    <th title="Speed Through Water - Boat speed">STW</th>
                    <th title="Average True Wind Angle">ATWA</th>
                    <th title="Average Bearing To Waypoint">ABTW</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="pointsTable" align="center">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="localtimeDiv">
        <input type="checkbox" id="localtime" tabindex="-1">
        <label>Local Time</label>
    </div>
    <div id="versionDiv">
        <label>Version</label>
        <label id="version"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="gpxDiv">
        <input class="cssButton" type="button" id="gpxExport" value=".GPX" tabindex="-1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <textarea id="gpxOutput" rows="2" readonly tabindex="-1">...:::Click on GPX button for generate file :::...
Select All | Copy selection | Paste on your text editor | Save the file with the .gpx extension</textarea>
</body>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

and this css code

```
body {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.table-wrap {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-wrap table {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-wrap table th, .table-wrap table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

tr:hover td {
     background-color: lightgray;
}

tr {
     background-color: white;
}

#localtimeDiv {
    float: left;
}

#versionDiv {
    float: right;
}

#gpxDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.cssButton {
    font-size: 11px;
}

#gpxOutput {
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
    resize: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

When I click on it I get this

[Screen_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKWMy.png)

I scroll down and I get this

[screen_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEVhd.png)

I wish that when I scroll  is always visible like this (it's a photo montage)

[screen_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W872k.png)

How can I put this in place ?

Edit: I can not set a fixed width the table is never the same and also evolves when checking the Local Time checkbox

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your table at the top of your page?

Comment: Yes the table is always at the top of the page (popup in reality)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which uses just a bit of JS to CSS `translateY` the `THEAD` within a wrapping DIV

```js
// Fix table head
function tableHeadFix(ev) {
  const el = ev.target;
  el.querySelector("thead").style.transform = `translateY(${el.scrollTop}px)`;
}

[...document.querySelectorAll(".table-wrap")].forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener("scroll", tableHeadFix)
);
```

```css
.table-wrap{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px 4px;
}

th {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th title="Timezone">TZ</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th title="Time To Waypoint">TTW</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="pointsTable" align="center">
        <tr><td>a1</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a2</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a3</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a4</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a5</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a6</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a7</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td></tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it works if I replace in the css

```
.table-wrap table th, .table-wrap table td {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 1px;
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

by

```
.table-wrap table th {
position: sticky;
top: 3px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: white;
}

.table-wrap table td {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 1px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Thanks @JBDouble05, your code suits me perfectly

Thanks too @Roko C. Buljan